# Mimic ORM in Angular

Tags: angularjs, orm

Assuming I have a list of items (i.e products) which are returned from the server and being displayed using `ng-repeat`, is there a way to "cast" or "wrap" each product within the results into a custom Javascript Object so that I could call pre-defined methods on it (similar to how server side ORM will take database data and wrap them with a pre-defined class, making properties and methods available without further action needed).

i.e a simple example, assume I have a `Product` class:

```
function Product() {
     this.getTotal = function() {
         return this.price * this.qty;//qty and price are available for each product in products
     }
}
```

and the list of products is resolved on the route level and is injected to the angular controller:

```
mainApp.controller("viewController", ['$scope', 'products', function ($scope, products) {}
```

In my HTML I want to be able to do the following:

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="product in products">
   <td>{{ product.getTotal() }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So an elegant solution ideally will look something like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products as Product">
   <td>{{ product.getTotal() }}</td>
</tr>
```

Or

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products | castTo:Product">
   <td>{{ product.getTotal() }}</td>
</tr>
```

Obviously I could iterate through the result upon receiving and instantiate each as an instance of Product, however I am looking for either a built in solution in Angular or a more elegant approach which is easily readable and can be used with any collection of objects.

My current thought is to create a filter which will do that, but before I re-invent the wheel, I would like to see if there is a better way.

Comment: Let me see if I got your question.. you have a list of `products` and they have the *properties* `qty` and `price` and you're trying to get the total based on those properties.. so for example.. if in the index 1, you have product with `qty = 2` and `price = 3`, the total would be 6, is it right?

Comment: @developer033 Yes, it is a simple example. In real life I want many methods available on each product. Basically want them to behave as a custom model/object.

Comment: You already have them as `objects`..

Comment: @developer033 Of course. But they are simple objects not inherited from any class. I want each product to be an instance of the Product class.